# How I check if one oval inside the ather?

Tags: java

I have a function but is not work good

there are the ovals

```
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(irx, iry, 10, 10);

    g.setColor(raco);
    g.fillOval(irx+1, iry+1, 8, 8);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(myX, myY, w, h);

    g.setColor(setco);
    g.fillOval(myX+1, myY+1, w-1, w-1);
```

there are the function

```
eated = isCollision( myX, myY, w, irx,iry,10);

private static boolean isCollision(double a1, double b1, float r1, double    a2, double b2, float r2)
{
    /*double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    x1 = a1 + r1/2;
    y1 = b1 - r1/2;

    x2 = a2 + r2/2;
    y2 = b2 - r2/2;*/

    float a,dx, dy;
    a = (r1+r2) * (r1+r2);
    dx = (float) (a1 - a2);
    dy = (float) (b1 - b2);

    if (a > (dx*dx) + (dy*dy))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a function that works well thank you and have a nice day ! ! !

Comment: Hi. What's your problem? What's your question? It's unclear what you're asking so don't expect to get any answer.

Comment: `I have a function but is not work good` followed by `I have a function that works well thank you`.... i'm confused

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to check for overlapping circles you can do it like: assuming we got 2 circles `c1` and `c2` if the distance between their centers is less than radius of c1 + radius of c2 they overlap

Comment: On a performance side-note: If this is for a game, you should really consider whether the extra resources needed to calculate a more precise collision between ovoid objects is really necessary. Hitboxes are boxes for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on my telepathy module.

AFAIR `drawOval`/`fillOval` get coordinates of top left corner, height and with of bounding box of oval. And your `isCollision` get centers and radiuses of circles.

You should convert one to another. remember that centerX = topLeftX + width/2.

Comment: I asked my Turing Oracle. It answered `Question must be more precies` :( could you mail me your telepathy module? It seems to be working better than my oracle.

Comment: @Turing85 Sorry it is too big to fit in mailbox.

Comment: aw, damn. Can you provide a download link?

Comment: @Turing85 it is hardware module. So give me id of your teleport station and I send you a copy when replicator finish it.